# UrlBinding parameters contain special characters

Tags: java, special-characters, javabeans, stripes, urlbinding

I'm passing parameters to `@UrlBinding` that contain special characters, for example:

`@UrlBinding("/url/test/{input}")` where `input=~!@#$%^-*()_+-=-][-;-.,---:-{}|-;` (basically just a list of special characters)

The resulting value gets cut off, so when I print out the `private String input` in java it only contains `~!@`

Looks like the `#` character is triggering some cut off behavior...can anyone direct me to documentation about this or explain what Stripes allows in these parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure it's the same as URL itself, here is from wiki:

List of allowed URL characters
Unreserved
(May be encoded but it is not necessary):
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 - _ . ~

Reserved
(Have to be encoded sometimes)
! * ' ( ) ; : @ & = + $ , / ? % # [ ]